# js code when select dropdown for second time the page have to reload

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I need a js function to say if I change the selection for next time the page have to load, that mean the selection for first time do nothing.

Comment: set a global variable on first change,and on change if set then reload.

Comment: could you please give me a code example ?